# how to use angular and apache on same nginx with same domain

Tags: php, angular, wordpress, apache, nginx

**TLDR:** configure nginx to listen on port 80 and use

- if `/api`, expressJS on `localhost:8081`
- if `/blog`, wordpress/apache2 on `localhost:8082`
- else angular server `localhost:8080`
  angular and express servers working but need to configure wordpress/apache.

**In detail,**
I have installed followings on same VPS:

1. `angular` frontend on port `8080`
2. `expressJS` backend on port `8081`
3. WordPress running on `apache2` on port 8082

Currently, I'm using nginx to manipulate requests and the config is

```
server {
        listen 443;

        ssl      on;
        ssl_certificate         /home/user/.ssh/ssl/ssl.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key     /home/user/.ssh/ssl/ssl.key.txt;

        root /var/www/html;

        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html index.php;

        server_name _;

        location / {
                proxy_set_header        Host $host;
            proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_pass          http://localhost:8080;
            proxy_read_timeout  90;
        }

        location /api {
                proxy_set_header        Host $host;
            proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_pass          http://localhost:8081;
            proxy_read_timeout  90;
        }
}
```

Now I need to host my blog on `mysite.com/blog`. so I added followings to nginx config.

```
 location /blog {
                proxy_set_header        Host $host;
            proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_pass          http://localhost:8082;
            proxy_read_timeout  90;
        }
```

Now when I go to `example.com/blog`, it redirects to `example.com:8082/blog`.  How to configure nginx and apache together?

*PS: Apache isn't required as long as wordpress works. But I like to keep nginx*

*PPS: I have configured nginx to forward all `http` requests to `https://example.com/` via redirect 301*

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an additional `/`at the end of the `proxy_pass` parameter to make it a complete URI (and not just a protocol/hostname/port combo) in order for Nginx to take care of the URL rewrite :

```
location /blog/ {
  ...
  proxy_pass http://localhost:8082/;
  ...
}
```

It will then remove the `/blog` prefix to the requested URL and append the remainer to the `http://localhost:8082/` root URL.

From the [Nginx documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) :

> A request URI is passed to the server as follows:
>
> If the proxy_pass directive is specified with a URI, then when a
>   request is passed to the server, the part of a normalized request URI
>   matching the location is replaced by a URI specified in the directive:
>
> `location /name/ {
>       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1/remote/; 
>     }`
>
> If proxy_pass is specified without a URI, the request URI is passed to the server in the same
>   form as sent by a client when the original request is processed, or
>   the full normalized request URI is passed when processing the changed
>   URI:
>
> `location /some/path/ {
>       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1; 
>   }`

Alternatively, you can force the URL rewriting manually using the `rewrite`directive :

```
location /blog/ {
  rewrite    /blog/?(.*) /$1 break;
  proxy_pass http://localhost:8082;
}
```

This should address your immediate issue, but if you want to get rid of Apache HTTP server and the reverse proxy directive altogether, you can take a look at [PHP FastCGI](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/phpfcgi/) to serve Wordpress/PHP directly from Nginx.

Comment: I added the `/` but same result. Tested on different device and incognito mode.

Comment: @SalithaIndrajithPathiraja try by also adding a `/`at the end of the `/blog` location as I've done in the edited answer.

Comment: No sir, still same result.

Comment: @SalithaIndrajithPathiraja what is the complete URL you're trying to access ?

Comment: @SalithaIndrajithPathiraja try "example.com/blog/" to see if it works at all, otherwise re-check your configuration file and ensure its correctly reloaded. If it still fails, try the manual URL rewriting alternative.

Comment: no.. I'll try with `fastCGI` again.. BTW thanks for the knowledge